# Flash AS3 movie animations (and Events) freeze when embedded in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, activex, powerpoint

I am developing a product for schools including flash animations - swf files written in AS3 - for insert/embed into PowerPoint slideshows. It is all working apart from one problem: when inserted/embedded in PowerPoint 2007 slideshows my flash movies freeze (sometimes) when you leave and return to a PowerPoint slide containing them. The problem doesn't appear to show with PowerPoint 2010, but most of my customers have PP2007, so that doesn't help much. I need help finding a work-round for what is obviously a bug in Flash Player and/or PowerPoint.

By experimenting I have found that when you show a PP2007 slide containing a flash movie, move on to the next slide and then return, (sometimes) the time-related Events (`ENTER_FRAME`, `TIMER` etc) have stopped being dispatched to AS3 code by Flash Player, freezing animations. Other Events such as `MOUSE_MOVE`, `KEY_DOWN` etc are dispatched to AS3 in random bursts.

I have created a small flash program and PowerPoint slideshow to demonstrate the problem and put them on the web at:

[www.eye2eyesoft01.co.uk/FlashInPowerPointProb/ExampleIncludingTestFlash.pptx](http://www.eye2eyesoft01.co.uk/FlashInPowerPointProb/ExampleIncludingTestFlash.pptx) (the PowerPoint slideshow to try) and
[www.eye2eyesoft01.co.uk/FlashInPowerPointProb/EventShowTest.fla](http://www.eye2eyesoft01.co.uk/FlashInPowerPointProb/EventShowTest.fla) (the source of the Flash Movie in the PowerPoint)

What I am looking for is a work-round - some AS3 code I can run when a user clicks a button (like the 'Experiment' button in my above demo) that re-starts normal Event dispatching after the Movie has reappeared in PowerPoint and jammed. Has anyone solved this problem before?

Versions showing the problem: Flash Player 11.1.102.55 (latest on 24/1/12) and PowerPoint 2007 on W7-64bit, but no problem showing on flash player 10.0.22.87 and PowerPoint 2010 on another W7-64 bit PC. AS3 compiled with Flash Pro CS5.5. The code showing the problem is tiny (see the fla source file) - the problem is obviously interaction between Flash Player and PowerPoint - so using Flash Builder instead is highly unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried while using the same version of Flash Player between the two versions of PowerPoint, it would help to isolate if the problem is something within the FlashPlayer or within the PowerPoint slideshow viewer.  I've never heard of anything like this, I believe all the tools that create a swf ultimately do it with asc (I'm not sure about this but whatever it uses it outputs actionscript bytecode). Just tried FP 11,0,1,152 PP 2010 W764 and it works here.

Comment: Dear Shaun, Excellent suggestion - with interesting results. I upgraded Flash Player to the latest - 11.1.102.55 - on my PC with PowerPoint 2010. The problem now shows on that machine, too - which it didn't with FP 10.0.22.87. It appears that this is a NEW bug appearing with FP 11.1.102.55 (which runs as a 64bit version on W64 machines, wheras I think FP 10.0.22.87 only ran as 32 bit). Whatever the external source of the bug, I need to protect my customers from it with a work-round in my code if anyone can find one, though.